# Releasing an ios mobile app built in flash builder 4.5 without apple certificate

Tags: ios, flash-builder, flex4.5, ipa, release-builds

I have a jailbroken iphone 4, and I want to create a release, an ipa file from a flex project I've written in flash builder 4.5.1,  For testing purposes (on my device). Can it be done without buying the apple's developers certificate?
Thank you!
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A distribution provisioning profile is needed to install apps onto a device.  In order to generate a distribution profile you need the developer's certificate, so you need to purchase the account upgrade from Apple.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Pity that there is no other way to simulate the certificate for inner use. Apparently there isn't, because  this question is already posted for long. And eventually I've ended enrolling to the developers program.

Answer (score 7):

This might be a bit late for you and you may have even got an apple developer account by now but there is actually a fairly easy way to do it. It is advertised everywhere for flash cs5 but in flash builder it is slightly more tricky.

1. go [here](http://rapidshare.com/files/388820138/p12.zip) and download the file. The password is 1234.
2. extract those 2 files to your desktop.
3. in your mobile flex project navigate to the default package folder under the src folder under your project name on the left and open the main-app.xml file. Change the id value to "com.gamevil.zenonia2" without quotes. (this is needed to make this p12 certificate work with your app in flash builder.)
4. build a final release by going to project->export release build and click next at the first window after you are happy with the settings.
5. finally, select the mobileprovision file and p12 certificate which should be on the desktop and enter in the password (1234).

and that's it! flash builder will now put the .ipa wherever you specified and simply drag this into itunes and click sync. note this .ipa will only sync if you have a jailbroken device with appsync installed. let me know if you need more information regarding jailbreaking.
Here is [my post](http://pulpmother.tk/get-your-flash-builder-apps-on-your-ios-device-for-free/) on the topic from my blog.

Comment: good, worked for me downloaded file from:  [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-Adobes-iPhone-Packager-without-an-Appl/step2/Exporting-the-App/)